# Error in getting action parameter in MVC controller from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to pass values from javascript to my controller action.

```
 $.getJSON('/gallery/PublishImage', { imageid: itemsarray }, function (mydata) {

    });
```

In javascript, it have a value. At the controller, it is null

```
 public ActionResult PublishImage(string imageid)
    {
        var mydata = imageid;
        return Json(mydata,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

how to resolve this.

my entire code is:

```
function publish() {
    debugger;

    var $trash = $("#trash li");
    var itemsarray = [];


    var lis = document.getElementById("trash").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        var item = lis[i].children[0].id;
        itemsarray.push(item);
    }


    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("PublishImage")', { imageids: itemsarray }, function (mydata) {


    });
```

in controller

```
public ActionResult PublishImage(string[] imageids)
    {
        var mydata = imageids;
        return Json(mydata,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

for testig  used string. but in the above code also return null.
is any thing am missed?

Comment: what is the serverside technology ? did you try `$.post` ?

Comment: How does `itemsarray` look like?

Comment: itemarray is a string. i need to get the values from my li tag and pass it to controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the name of this javascript variable I strongly suspect that `itemsarray` is not a string but some kind of javascript object (an array?). It must be string for this to work:

```
var itemsarray = 'foo bar';
$.getJSON('/gallery/PublishImage', { imageid: itemsarray }, function (mydata) {

});
```

If you want to send an array then you could do that:

```
var itemsarray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
$.getJSON('/gallery/PublishImage', { imageids: itemsarray }, function (mydata) {

});
```

and your controller action:

```
public ActionResult PublishImage(string[] imageids)
{
    var mydata = imageids;
    return Json(mydata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: i got it. i added the type : post and my code is  $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("PublishImage")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ imageids: itemsarray }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type:'POST',
            success: function (mydata) {
                alert(mydata);
            }
        });